# How to make input fields accept number types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am using d3.js with TS. I have two input fields which are not accepting number types, what I want is to accept the input in the two fields and plot the points on the scatterplot graph.

This is what the UI looks like currently after inputting a number:

[image]

The points are not created according to the graph measurement inputs.

The chart code (D3BarChart.ts), creation of graph and axes:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
export const dataset1: number[][] = [];

export class scatterGraph {
  constructor() {
    // chart size (without axes)
    const width = 150;
    const height = 150;

    const axisLabelXOffset = 5; // gap to bottom svg border
    const axisLabelYOffset = 15; // gap to left svg border

    // margin contains axes (left/bottom) or blank spcae (top/right)
    const margin = {
      // contains axes
      top: 10,
      right: 10, //necessary as x-axis labels may be wider than the chart
      bottom: 30 + axisLabelXOffset,
      left: 30 + axisLabelYOffset
    };

    const svg = d3
      .select('#my_dataviz')
      .append('svg')
      .classed('chart1', true)
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, width]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 200]).range([height, 0]);

    //Creating x label
    svg
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', width / 2 + margin.left) // center in the chart
      .attr('y', height + margin.bottom + margin.top - axisLabelXOffset)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('font-family', 'Helvetica')
      .style('font-size', 9)
      .text('Independant');

    //Creating y label
    svg
      .append('text')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
      .attr('y', axisLabelYOffset)
      .attr('x', -(height / 2 + margin.top))
      .style('font-family', 'Helvetica')
      .style('font-size', 9)
      .text('Dependant');

    //Plot group, contains axis & marks
    const plot = svg
      .append('g')
      .classed('plot', true)
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    //Create axes
    plot
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    plot.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    // Create scatter plot, data points displayed.
    plot
      .append('g')
      .selectAll('dot')
      .data(dataset1)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', d => xScale(d[0]))
      .attr('cy', d => yScale(d[1]))
      .attr('r', 2)
      .style('fill', '#CC0000');
  }
}
```

This is how it should look once the data is inputted into the array(static data):
`export const dataset1: number[][] = [[50,10]];`

The other code (MlProvSidebar.ts):

```
import { Widget } from '@lumino/widgets';
import { offlineBoltIcon } from '@jupyterlab/ui-components';
import { scatterGraph } from './D3BarChart';
import { Message } from '@lumino/messaging';
import { dataset1 } from './D3BarChart';

const metric =
  '<input size = "15" id = "hyper1"> &nbsp; <input size = "15" id = "hyper2"> <button id = "submitButton" style = "border-radius: 15px;"> Submit </button> <div style = "margin-bottom: 1cm;"></div>';
const dataviz = '<div id = "my_dataviz"></div>';
export class MlProvSidebar extends Widget {
  /**
   * Returns a new table of contents.
   *
   * @param options - options
   * @returns widget
   */
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addClass('ml-prov-widget-view');
    this.id = 'ml-prov-widget';
    this.title.label = TITLE;
    this.title.caption = DESCRIPTION;
    this.title.icon = offlineBoltIcon; //placeholder, see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/packages/ui-components for how to add icons
    this.title.closable = true;
    this.addStaticDummyContent();
  }

  addStaticDummyContent(): void {
    this.node.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'afterbegin',
      `
      <h1>${TITLE}</h1>
      <p>${DESCRIPTION}</p>
      <ul>${values}</ul>
      ${metric}
      ${dataviz}
    `
    );
  }
//get value of two inputs and push to array, dataset1
  protected onBeforeShow(msg: Message): void {
    console.debug(`Opening ${TITLE} sidebar.`);
    const element = document.getElementById(
      'submitButton'
    ) as HTMLButtonElement;
    const hyperInput: any = (<HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById('hyper1')
    )).value;
    const hyperInput2:any = (<HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById('hyper2')
    )).value;
    element?.addEventListener('click', () => {
      dataset1.push(hyperInput);
      dataset1.push(hyperInput2);
      const updateGraph = new scatterGraph();
      return updateGraph;
    });
  }
}
```

To save time, the `onBeforeShow()` function and variable `metric` is used for the input issue (MlProvSidebar.ts).

Comment: I assume this is the line you are asking about...if so, you should be able to make two small changes for this to work: `const hyperInput: number = +(<HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById('hyper1'))).value;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but I get this error: ```Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.```  in the next part where I push the data to the array (dataset1). This line: ```dataset1.push(hyperInput);```

Comment: yeah, so I would assume you would want `dataset1.push([hyperInput, hyperInput2])`, but it is a little hard to say without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have made your change, but now the dot is at the origin of the scatterplot. Also, I can't show a reproducible environment since it's on Jupyter lab but I have created a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-tree-n0fp9?file=/src/MlProvSidebar.ts and I have a screen record of how it works: https://youtu.be/1CshJJ-oSNA